# Mounting several applications with CherryPy and gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn, cherrypy

My folder directory is as follows:

```
Root
   - App1
      - handlers.py
   - App2
      - handlers.py
   - wsgi.py
```

I want to use Cherrypy to mount apps to their respective urls: server.com/app1, server.com/app2 and create a WSGI entry point to Gunicorn.

wsgi.py:

```
import cherrypy
from App1.handlers import App1 as App1Handler
from App2.handlers import App2 as App2Handler

application = cherrypy.tree.mount(App2Handler(), '/app2', {})
cherrypy.tree.mount(App1Handler(), '/app1', {})

cherrypy.config.update({'engine.autoreload.on': False})
cherrypy.config.update({'environment': 'embedded'})
cherrypy.server.unsubscribe()
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

I can get to app2 but trying to reach app1 shows 'path not found'. How do I mount both apps as a WSGI entry point? Cherrypy's tutorials didn't show how to combine external WSGI server with mounting multiple applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change in your `wsgi.py`:

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(App1Handler(), '/app1', {})
cherrypy.tree.mount(App2Handler(), '/app2', {})
application = cherrypy.tree
```

Then launch with something like:

```
gunicorn wsgi:application
```